Save and load column arrangements in QGIS
In QGIS, I sometimes work with layers that have many columns in their attribute table. I can arrange these columns using the 'organize columns' function to suit my needs. Occasionally, there are up to three different arrangements that are ideal for my various tasks. Is it possible to save a column arrangement so that I can load a specific arrangement for a particular task? With filters, this is possible, but is it also possible with columns?

You can save empty versions of each arrangement, and then copy and paste into one of those with your new data, to in effect re-organize it.

how do I safe empty versions and copy and paste them?
I reformulate the question to be sure it is understood correctly. I have one layer with many columns/fields. Depending on the task, I move fields 'a', 'b' and 'c' from the right side of my attribute table to the very left.
On an other day I need to work with the fields x, y and z and move them to very left and a, b, and c I move further right of the attribute table. Ideally, there is a list where I can load or pick a pre-defined arrangement.

Set up attribute column layout using "organize columns".
Save that as a layer definition file (*.qlr) with a name that identifies your column layout, eg layer_abc.qlr.
Set up another attribute column layout using "organize columns".
Save that as a different layer definition file (*.qlr) with a name that identifies your column layout, eg layer_xyz.qlr.
When you want the "a b c" column layout, add the layer_abc.qlr layer file.  And when you want the "x y z" layout, load the layer_xyz.qlr layer file.


If you need to switch between configuration in the same project you may create several style for the same layer, each style will keep the field order and visibility that you configure while active. A convenient way to create and manage your styles is to use the Style Manager tab (the three paintbrush) from the Layer Styling panel (this is different from the main Style Manager).
Note that switching between style wont reload the attribute table so you will need to close and open the attribute table again to see the column configuration change after changing style.
